# How to get and split Array values in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

Good day I need help on how to get the specific value on an array.I want to get the qty value and id value. The array output is like this

{"items":{"2":{"qty":1,"price":300,"item":{"id":2,"title":"LOTR","author":"James Cameron","price":300,"quantity":150,"created_at":"2020-08-24T13:35:36.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-08-24T13:38:52.000000Z"}}},"totalQty":1,"totalPrice":300}

As for the code

public function postCheckout(Request $request){

```
    if (!Session::has('cart')){
         return view('shop.shoppingcart');

    }
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $order = new Order();
    $order->cart = json_encode($cart);
    $order->address = $request->input('address');
    $order->name = $request->input('name');

Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
   
    
   Session::forget('cart');   
}

public function findvalarray(){
    $order = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();
     return view("test", ['order' => $order]);

}
```

The one with $order->cart = json_encode($cart) is the part where all the products that have been added to cart.

While the findvalarray is the one to find the cart value in the database dont mind the limit cause I need it for selection of a specific date.

And this is the blade view

@foreach($order as $item)
{{$item['cart']}}

@endforeach

Appreaciate the reply thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `$order->cart` is in JSON format you need to `json_decode()` your cart to convert it to `array|object` so you can access it's value, in your blade you can do

```
@foreach($order as $item) 

   {{ dd(json_decode($item['cart'])) }}

@endforeach
```

The result will be an object that you can access like `json_decode($item['cart'])->totalQty`

```
{#260 ▼
  +"items": {#258 ▼
    +"2": {#257 ▼
      +"qty": 1
      +"price": 300
      +"item": {#251 ▼
        +"id": 2
        +"title": "LOTR"
        +"author": "James Cameron"
        +"price": 300
        +"quantity": 150
        +"created_at": "2020-08-24T13:35:36.000000Z"
        +"updated_at": "2020-08-24T13:38:52.000000Z"
      }
    }
  }
  +"totalQty": 1
  +"totalPrice": 300
}
```

If you want it as array you can do `dd(json_decode($item['cart'], true))` this will give you

```
array:3 [▼
  "items" => array:1 [▼
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "qty" => 1
      "price" => 300
      "item" => array:7 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "title" => "LOTR"
        "author" => "James Cameron"
        "price" => 300
        "quantity" => 150
        "created_at" => "2020-08-24T13:35:36.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-24T13:38:52.000000Z"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "totalQty" => 1
  "totalPrice" => 300
]
```

And you can access it like `json_decode($item['cart'])['totalQty']`

Comment: Thanks for the help but how can I get the value in the items like the number 2 in " +"items": {#258 ▼
    +"2": {#257 ▼" and the qty?

Comment: First you need to double check how you store items because it should start from index 0, but if you want to get keys you can use `array_keys(json_decode($item['cart'], true)['items'])` this will return the indices of items then you can loop and fetch each item.